# what is the best way to fix IE6 png trancparency with javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, png, transparency

is there any simple way to fix IE6 PNG transparency with javascript and jquery with out using any plug-in or something too complicated ?

Comment: sorta curious why you'd not want to use a plug-in

Comment: Using a plugin that inspects each DOM node is incredibly expensive.  It's best to do it by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this small plugin to do it for you:

http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/

However the main solution is build around the filters which are included in the IE rendering engine. These can be added by css or javascript.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="img.png");
```

Comment: Don't forget `background: none` before that `filter` line

Answer (score 2):

- [iepngfix](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iepngfix)
- [ifixpng](http://jquery.khurshid.com/ifixpng.php)
- [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) (doesn't use jQuery though)

Answer (score 1):

Ive had success using [this](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) (IEPngFix). Its a custom behavour that you can use by doing something like this...

```
<style type="text/css">
    img, div { behavior: url(iepngfix.htc) }
</style>
```

There online tutorial is [here](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/).

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of fixing this problem but one of the **nicest and lightest way** to fix the transparent PNG problem in IE6 is by using DD_belatedPNG. This lightweight but powerful Javascript library adds Transparent PNG image support to IE6 and **is only 5.5KB in size** so it won’t have a large impact on your website’s loading time. It’s simple to set up and it will fix CSS background-images as well as `<IMG/>` elements.

see more details here http://www.cre8ivecommando.com/ie6-png-fix-transparent-png-image-support-for-ie6-174/

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery pngfix plugin fixes *all* PNGs, which is a complicated proposition and likely more power than you need. It fixes:

- IMG tags
- CSS background images
- INPUT buttons that are images

To really answer your question, I'd need to know what all you need fixed, specifically. For example, if you only care about CSS background-image (likely if you're just doing soft drop shadows), then I'd recommend simply copy n' paste of the 8 lines from that plugin.

```
    // fix css background pngs
    jQuery(this).find("*").each(function(){
        var bgIMG = jQuery(this).css('background-image');
        if(bgIMG.indexOf(".png")!=-1){
            var iebg = bgIMG.split('url("')[1].split('")')[0];
            jQuery(this).css('background-image', 'none');
            jQuery(this).get(0).runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + iebg + "',sizingMethod='scale')";
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is incredibly expensive. It's best to assign a class to flag nodes for individual modification (e.g.: `class="fix-png"`).  In my own work I find that, typically, the "by hand" approach is much more appropriate

Comment: It not very expensive actually, since you'd call this code on specific elements (not the whole document).

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest using a transparent gif if IE6. On page load, do a [browser detect](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp), and set the image src in javascript as appropriate.

Comment: Using a GIF or 8-bit PNG might work in certain situations, but conditional comments and straight CSS is the right way to achieve a different image for IE6, not JavaScript + Browser Detection w/ JavaScript.

Comment: well depends on whether the img is set in html or css